# Measure theory, Showing a set A is $\mu^*$-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How should I approach the following problem: Let $A\subset X$, show $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable if there exist $B$ $\mu^*$ measurable such that $\mu^*(A-B)<\epsilon$ for each $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Is $\mu^*$ the outer measure used in the definition of the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes! I should also mention B\subset of A

Comment: Correction,  all we have is \mu^* is an outer measure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following approach should help you out: Recall that Carathéodory's Theorem shows that the set of $\mu^*$-measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra on which $\mu^*$ is a complete measure. Try using the fact that measures are continuous from above.

Hopefully this will help get the ball rolling!